# Bloomberg BQNT vs Dektop API

Tags: data, bloomberg

I am currently looking at alternatives to the Bloomberg Desktop API as I frequently reach the daily or even monthly data limit. One alternative which was proposed to me was switching from a desktop license to a Bloomberg Anywhere license since the BQNT environment which is offered under a BBA license would allow to run scripts in the Bloomberg cloud thus offering less restrictive data limits. Has anyone experience with BQNT vs. Dekstop API and can confirm this claim?

Comment: You can try BQL in excel. The queries in python will be the same. The trick is that you will pre-filter the data with BQL before using it in your analysis instead of pulling the entire data in a dataframe. Otherwise, the limits are exactly the same.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense.